# Erlang persistent data structures

Tags: clojure, erlang

As I've understood, when you create a new list with expression like the following, [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) doesn't copy `L1`, it just copies `H`.

```
L2 = [H|L1]
```

Does Erlang have persistent a data structure (see [Persistent data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)) for `dict`, that is, when you add/remove/modify nodes in the tree only few elements are being copied (like in [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure))?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have misunderstood the situation when you build a list using `[H|T]`. It is as you say that `T` is not copied but neither is `H`. All that happens is that a new list cell is prepended to `T` with a reference to `H` as its head (its tail is `T`). When working with lists the only bits which are created are the actual list cells and never the data in each cell.

The same happens when working with `dict`. When you modify (add/delete elements) in the `dict` only the actual `dict` structure is modified and not the actual data in the `dict`. Also it is smart so as to only copy as little of the `dict` structure as is necessary to make the modification.

So, yes, Erlang has persistent data structures. In that respect clojure is like Erlang (we were around long before it).

Comment: ok, we will not discuss here pointers and values, the difference is clear for me, the point is how to operate with big in-memory Key-Value stores that has persistence (so no ets). I've mentioned that in clojure during modification of some value only path from root to that value is copied (3-4 nodes) and we have two trees: the new and the old one. How can we do this in erlang? Does some structure from the box implement such behavior?

Comment: `A = SomeTree, B = change(A).` You now have the Tree B and the Tree A, where `B` is the new one and `A` is the old one.. Using `{A,B}` puts both trees in the same tuple. Is this what you wanted to know about?

Comment: nop, I need A = SomeTree, B = change(A), and A and B share some common piece, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional#Trees

Comment: If you reread rvirdings answer you'll see: "Also it is smart so as to only copy as little of the dict structure as is necessary to make the modification."  That's what you asked and you really got the copying wrong in your question, so it seems cons cells not so clear to you.  And the answer was "yes" just read to the end of it.

Comment: Yes, Erlang does purely functional trees and will only modify the path from the root down to the node which is modified. The `dict`, `gb_trees` and `array` libraries work in this fashion. The `lists` library as well though it works only on lists. It is the standard way of doing things so in principle all libraries which work on data structures do it.

Comment: to Peer Stritzinger - if you cannot understand the question and has nothing to write just do not write, question gives quite precise what I want to see in answer and rvirding is quite smart to give it, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the data structures for the library module do not degrade in performance or memory pressure when they get larger.

For a dict, it uses a dynamic hash table as internal data structure and work is done essentially only on the bucket where the modification is done.

I also looked in the `gb_trees` module where I found the comment:

> Behaviour is logaritmic (as it should be).

And `gb_trees` are generally pretty fast, so I'm quite sure not much copying is going on.

Generally, if you implement data structures like these in a language like Erlang, you take care of copying issues, so there is no need to worry about it for the general library functions.

---

I reread the article about persistent data structures: in the sense of this article, Erlang's data structures are fully persistent and also confluently persistent.

Comment: And what about linear structures? Is there such a thing as a vector (or a set for that matter) that have those performance guarantees?

Comment: Yes there is .. 'array' and fwiw 'set'  ... did you even try to look in the docs?